# How can I add an image to JS function?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to do a pac-man game and my code of the function for adding layout on the board looks like this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < layout.length; i++) {
    const square = document.createElement('div')
    grid.appendChild(square)
    squares.push(square)
    // add layout to the board // 
    if (layout[i] === 0) {
        squares[i].classList.add('pac-dot')
    } else if (layout[i] === 1) {
        squares[i].classList.add('wall')
    } else if (layout[i] === 3) {
        squares[i].classList.add('strawberry')
    }
}
```

I want to add an image to the squares in the classList `Strawberry` I tried creating a div on html and styling it with css but that didn't work out. I also tried the `img` tag with an id but it also did not work out.

How can I add an image to the squares?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: ```const square = new Image();
square.src = 'url/to/your/image.png';```

Comment: So what are the styles of the DIV. Seems like that is your problem if it is not showing an image. Show your CSS.

Comment: it looks like this `    div.image {
        background-image: url("");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        width: 10px;
        height: 20px;
        border-radius: 10px;
    }
    `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem with adding another function to the JS body like this:

```
function addImageToSquare(div, imgSource, height, width) {
    let img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = imgSource
    img.id = "picture"
    img.style.height = "25px"
    img.style.width = "25px"
    div.appendChild(img);
}
```

And I called the function with this

```
addImageToSquare(squares[i], "images/strawberry.png")
```

under

```
else if (layout[i] === 3) {
    squares[i].classList.add('strawberry')
```

Answer (score 0):

In strawberry class put a css style called background image

```
.strawberry {
background-image: url(""); 
/*
put image url in the url ("")
any url will work ex. images/myimage.jpg or www.web/image.jpg
*/
}
```

Comment: What should I write in html other than `<div class="straweberry"></div>` ? Or should I add something to js? Because I tried it with html and it didn´t work

Comment: @zsip I believe in you js you should add `squares[i].style.backgroundImage = "url('')";` and take out the background image in the strawberry class you can add the strawberry class after adding the background image